# Can't set more resolution

Tags: lubuntu, screen, display-resolution

Hi I'm using an old Vaio PCV-RX84M and using lubuntu. It has 700MB of RAM and a 32MB SIS651 graphics card. I connected the PC to an HD LED monitor which displayed a 1024x720 resolution. Then I did system updates and after restarting the resolution was only 640x400. I can't even see the full screen, please help. I already tried the configurations.